# Select max() in Google Sheet Query on Dates gives different result to =max() formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to return the last time log from a list in Google spreadsheet using Google Sheet query max() function.

```
=query(A:A, "select max(A)",1)
```

The time log data (column A) is in text format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, which is imported to google sheet using importdata function.

The above query is not returning the correct result. I think it's because the source of data is in text format.

e.g. The above query will return `9/9/2017 23:58:00` while the `normal =max(A:A)` function returns `12/9/2017 19:12:00`.

Is it possible to reformat the text to datetime format within the query clause?

The data sample is from here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EwT5ZvCCLLorWomaeJFMhAziWnhW9zTwco9dfwoXJJ4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible*, for example:

```
=query(ArrayFormula(1*filter(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))), "select max(Col1)",0)
```

(and probably something a bit simpler!) but the obvious preferred option is to treat date/times as date/times, not text.